# Finding a generator of a cyclic and totally ramified extension by using a generator of an unramified extension of the greater field of the same degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, ramification

Let $K$ be an extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ which contains a primitive $n$-th root unity. Also, assume that $p$ does not divide $n$. 
Let $L/K$ be a cyclic and totally ramified extension of degree $n$, and $L'/L$ be a cyclic and unramified extension of degree $n$.

Some result about cyclic extension states that there is an element $\beta \in L'$ such that $L' = L(\beta)$ with $\beta^n \in L$, and $n$ is the smallest power of $\beta$ which lies in $L$.

> **Question**: Is there a way of finding an element $\tilde{\beta} \in L$  such that $L = K(\tilde{\beta})$ with $\tilde{\beta}^n \in K$, and $n$ being the smallest power with that property, which uses $\beta^n \in L$?

I am not so sure about this point but from my computations with Sage, it seems to be not enough to just take $\tilde{\beta} = \beta^n$ (because its minimal polynomial does not necessarily split and therefore, the extension of $K$ generated by $\beta^n$ is not totally ramified in this case). This is where I am stuck now.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I find the question (specifically "which uses $\beta^n \in L$" -- uses as what or for what?) unclear, so that right now I cannot even tell if reuns' answer answers it or not. Please clarify.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: What I mean is that if a $\beta \in L'$ with the mentioned properties is given, how can I explicitly determine an $\tilde{\beta} \in L$ with the above mentioned properties which uses the information which the information $\beta^6$ provides. I am not sure if my question is formulated better that way. Reuns' response does not seems to answer my question - at least I cannot see how it is related to my question.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. "which uses the information which the information $\beta^6$ provides" is not clearer (to me) than what you wrote before. You seem to ask if one can just take $\tilde \beta :=\beta^n$ but answer that negatively yourself. So what else could one want?

Comment: Also, can one not explicitly describe all possible $\tilde \beta$ as described via Kummer theory? But then still, how do you want to relate them to that $\beta$?

Comment: The last sentence of your last comment is actually my question. So my question is if there is a general way of choosing $\tilde{\beta}$ - for instance, as a linear combination of $1,\beta^n, \dots, \beta^{(n-1)n}$ in a certain pattern which always works.And yes, I meant $\beta^n$ instead of $\beta^6$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $L/K$ is totally tamely ramified then $L= K(\pi_K^{1/n})$ and the residue field of $K$ thus of $L$ is $\Bbb{F}_q$ whence $L' = L(\zeta_{q^n-1})$.

Let $\sigma\in Gal(L'/L), \sigma(\zeta_{q^n-1})=\zeta_{q^n-1}^q$ (the canonical lift of the Frobenius of the residue fields, there is a canonical one because $L'/L$ is unramified, which is automatically cyclic)

$$a = \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \zeta_n^{-m}\sigma^m(\zeta_{q^n-1})\in K(\zeta_{q^n-1})$$ $\sigma^m(a) = \zeta_n^m a$, the $L$-conjugates of $a$ are $\zeta_n^m a$ so that its minimal polynomial is $X^n-a^n \in K[x]$ and $K(\zeta_{q^n-1})=K(a), L'=L(a)$.